# Obtener valor de un objeto

Tags: typescript

Tengo el siguiente código

```
introducir el código aquí

let exchange: any[];

//CODE - En algún momento se le asigna un valor a esa variable
exchange = { USD: 0.8307028, EUR: 1, BRL: 0.15311825}
```

Ahora quisiera coger el valor por ejemplo de BRL

```
console.log(this.exchange["BRL"])
```

pero me da error : **Element implicity has an any type because index expression is not of type number**

Answer (score 1):

Has declarado la variable exchange como lista de `any` (`any[]`), cuando debería ser simplemente `any`.

El error te dice que `"BRL"` no es un índice válido para obtener elementos de un array, ya que no es un número.